# Need an ASP.Net eCommerce app that I can make specific changes to (MVC preferred)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, e-commerce

I'm planning to set up an online store for a friend, unfortunately his product line introduces some demands most out-of-the-box solutions don't fit.  I'm hoping somebody here has had some experiences with an open source package that they can recommend.

The specific issue is that the products are going to number in the hundreds of thousands.  Since the type of products have a lot of clearly defined specifics, searching and sorting can be (and needs to be) very granular and efficient.  For this reason, the primary requirement is that I replace the product and search-related parts of the app, but only those parts.  I'm hoping that there's an ecommerce solution with the product segment abstracted so that I can change the database tables, product display code, search code, and create the obvious code to interact with the database.

I'd prefer something that's built on ASP.Net MVC since it'll play nicely with some extensions I am considering for the future but I'd consider WebForms.  I'd also like it to be something that functions on GoDaddy's Hosting, though I'm not optimistic, I just got the account before I discovered how terrible of an ASP.Net web host they are.  And finally I need something that's reasonably mature as I don't have time up front to deal with a system that hasn't been tested, and the majority of issues worked through already.

I'd appreciate any ideas.

Edit: I've done a bit of searching already and I've found several (at least 8) MVC projects, but I haven't had time to examine them properly for the needs listed above.  I also can't be sure which ones have matured from real world application...So I'm mostly looking for advice either based on a familiarity with using the app or at least reading enough about it that you would feel it's good to recommend.

Thanks Everybody!

Comment: Please consider some other hosting solutions than GoDaddy. If you exceed any of their limits you will have to pay a lot of money.

Comment: To begin with, I would never leave my credit card on file with them, so they won't get more money out of me (and if they did charge the card, they open themselves up to credit card fraud which cost them far more).
I got a better than average deal on hosting and while I'd heard complaints, I didn't know the nature of ALL of their limits until later.
Finally, and I hope this doesn't come across rudely, but I wasn't asking about GoDaddy, just including it as a note.  I'll make very little on this project, so I'd like to find a use for the hosting account while it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://code.google.com/p/sutekishop/

Comment: Just curious, have you used/implemented Suteki Shop?  I took a very brief look at it a couple of weeks back and dismissed it at the time because it stood no chance of working with GoDaddy (Linq-to-SQL and Windsor IoC both blow that).  Since relaxing that restriction at bit, I'm curious about your experience with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://thebeerhouse.codeplex.com/

Comment: Again, I've only had time to briefly peek at TheBeerHouse, but the time I had to look at it so far, I got the impression the product database was pretty tightly ingrained.  Have you had any experiences with this one?